# RealmDB React Native - Objetos vazio no RealmDB, quando vou criar e listar os objetos

Tags: react-native, realmdb

Opa pessoal, tudo certo? Estou tendo um problema com meu RealmDB aqui, estou tentando criar um novo objeto e tentando listar esses objetos criados. Porem, ao listar ou criar, ele me retorna objetos vazios. Segue o exemplo:

**Exemplo de uso:**

```
const Store = {
    name: 'Store',
    properties: {
        storeId: {type: 'int'},
        storeName: {type: 'string'}
    }
};

export default new Realm({schema: [Store], schemaVersion: 20});
```

Aqui, quando eu gravo, ele já me retorna um objeto vazio. Porem ele adiciona...

```
 realm.write(() => {
     realm.create('Stores', {storeId: 1, storeName: "My Store"});
 });
```

Quando tento ler

```
 let stores = realm.objects('Stores');
```

Recebo isso

```
[{}]
```

**OBS:** Tentei listar esses objetos em um componente, mas mesmo assim não tem dados.

Comment: `realm.objects('Stores'))` um `)` a mais, foi erro de escrita?

Comment: Escrevi errado aqui, eu abri o realm. Mas deu o mesmo problema ainda.

Answer (score -2):

Em vez assim:

```
let stores = realm.objects('Stores'))
```

Tenta assim:

```
let stores = realm.objects('Stores')
```

Comment: Opa, acabei escrevendo errado aqui. Mas tentei também, mesmo problema ainda :(